# How to: Send two or more vars from javascript to a .php file

Tags: php, mysql, xmlhttprequest

I have a javascript function

```
function editarProducto(cantidad, precio, id)
{
alert("Id del producto "+id);
alert("Cantidad "+cantidad);
alert("Precio "+precio);//It works! i Got the 3 values here

xmlhttp.open("POST","modificaCotizacion.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.send("id="+id,"cantidad="+cantidad,"precio="+precio);//<-----
location.reload(true)
}
```

Is correct the way i'm trying to send my vars?

xmlhttp.send("id="+id,"cantidad="+cantidad,"precio="+precio);//<------

I tryied it, but it doesn't work...
It's like modificaCotizacion don't recieve my vars....

I tryied with it too:

```
xmlhttp.send("id="+id);
xmlhttp.send("precio="+precio);
xmlhttp.send("cantidad="+cantidad);
```

My php file code is:

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');
$con = conexion();
$idproducto= $_POST['id'];
$cantidad= $_POST['cantidad'];
$precio= $_POST['precio'];
?>
<script>
alert("Alerta");
</script> //even the script doesnt work!
<?php
mysql_query("UPDATE prec SET cantidad='$cantidad', precio='$precio' WHERE idproducto='$id'",$con)or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

any idea?

**thank you**

Comment: You should read up on sql injection and switch to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements.

Comment: You're apparently ignoring advice on dealing with your rampant [SQL injection problems](http://bobby-tables.com/). This application is full of holes that, if it were deployed on the public internet, would be an enormous liability. Please, take the time to fix these things before they cost you dearly.

Answer (score 1):

```
xmlhttp.send("id="+id+"&cantidad="+cantidad+"&precio="+precio);
```

Should do the trick

Here is some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send())

Comment: @Jean, this is a different problem. The alert in your script will only be processed by the browser once the server has issued a HTTP response and the client has processed that response. Since the response is handled by your JavaScript code the `script` element containing the alert will not be appended to the DOM. Unless you do so yourself.

Comment: Is there a way to comrpbe is really I'm recieving the values??

Comment: Check your database to see if the values were changed.

Comment: I think you should ask a separate question, if you want further help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send multiple parameters, you need to add them as a query string, you cannot send multiple parameters separately to `.send()`.

You should also escape your values using `encodeURIComponent()` in case the values can contain characters that are not valid in a query string:

```
xmlhttp.send("id="+encodeURIComponent(id)+"&cantidad="+encodeURIComponent(cantidad)+"&precio="+encodeURIComponent(precio));
```

Comment: BUT The alert in my php file is not displayed yet

Comment: @Jean It's an ajax call and everything you output will be returned to the javascript. As it all happens server-side - and you are not doing anything with the output anyway - a javascript alert will never show.

Comment: Is there a way to comprobe is really I'm recieving the values??

Comment: @Jean You need to add a success function that processes the results of your ajax call (the output of your php script). In plain javascript that would be `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {}`. You can also see what's returned in the console of your browser tools.

Comment: @Jean If you want to know how to accomplish this I suggest that you do some research, try to figure that out for yourself. Then if you are still having problems post another question.